# Is it possible to suppress loopback of broadcasted packets?

Tags: .net, sockets, udp, broadcast

I have a .NET program that "listens" and broadcasts on the same port. So, when it broadcasts packets, these packets loop back to my program, and I wish it didn't happen.

Is there a way to block broadcast loopback?

Comment: Filtering where a broadcast goes would make it something other than a broadcast...

Comment: @Adam Robinson: Filtering their loopback seems like a decent objective to me. The option is even present for multicast packets with the `MulticastLoopback` property.

Comment: I'm not saying that it isn't a decent objective, but there's a conceptual difference between filtering against Loopback and filtering against a particular address that just *happens* to be on the same machine.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: can't you assume that broadcasted packets will arrive on the same interface they sailed from? In that case, it will be somewhat more significant. Besides, I don't expect it to be possible by not sending it to the host; I was more thinking about the socket discarting packets that it sent.

Comment: Sure, you can assume that, but not everything that broadcasts also listens in the same manner that it broadcasts. In terms of discarding packets that it sent, is this something that's a great deal of trouble to do in code?

Comment: @Adam Robinson: of course, it's not everyone's case. If it were, there would be an obvious solution. It's not too much trouble and it works to just discard packets that are from the sending socket, but it's not especially gracious, so I was wondering if there was a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost a year with no solution, I suppose it's not possible.